# Configure Exim to work with IPv6 and G Suite

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, exim, g-suite

I am planning to enable IPv6 on some servers that use Exim only to send emails.
Do I need to do any special configuration in Exim when enabling IPv6?

This concern came after a user of a VPS service reported the following:

> The ipv6 activation alters the name of the server.
>
> This invalidates MX records with the server name

Another question I have doubts. I use G Suite to manage my domain emails, especially for receiving emails.
Since I use Exim to send emails from the server my domain points to, do I need to configure anything for using G Suite to receive / send emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your IPv6 address has a PTR record. The same as with IPv4, Google will reject unauthenticated mail coming from IPv6 addresses with no PTR record.

The quote you gave from "a user of a VPS service" doesn't seem to make a lot of sense here. Perhaps he made the mistake of naming his server with the naked domain name. This should never be done with a server that sends/receives mail, but doesn't handle mail for the domain, as some mail will then get lost. That is, the server's configured hostname should be `whatever.example.com`, but never `example.com` alone.

Comment: If it is then two servers (load balancing), the correct would be the hostname of each server to be something like machine1.example.com and mache2.example.com, and put these values ​​only in dc_other_hostnames, correct?

Comment: @Tom Do you intend for machine1.example.com to accept mail for machine2.example.com?

Comment: These servers will only send emails to external domains. No emails will be received on these servers.

Comment: @Tom Then the names shouldn't be listed in `dc_other_hostnames`. This specifies domains for which that machine receives mail, and will never forward it outside.

Comment: In this case then the value should be just localhost.localdomain and localhost?

I was using this article as a reference [How To Install the Send-Only Mail Server "Exim"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-send-only-mail-server-exim-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: @Tom Other than the fact that that article is a bit out of date, yes, that option refers to receiving mail. Mail for domains specified there will never be sent out.

Comment: Thank you for your help.